# Exim: Redirect mails without spooling

Tags: smtp, spam, exim, redirection

I am running a personal mail server using exim that only forwards mails (and also runs a few mailman mailing lists).

Unfortunately, my server’s spam protection is worse than that of the mail provider I forward most mails to (mailbox.org). So my server might accept an email, try to send it to mailbox.org’s MX, that will reject it, and now my server might generate a bounce message. Which then often can’t be delivered and would then be frozen.

Can I configure exim to try to forward the mail *before* finally accepting it, and if the downstream server does not like it, simply reject it as well, so that my server never creates bounce messages in that situation?

Comment: This would net you a new annoying special case: The delivering mail server assumes the delivery was unsuccessful before your redirect target responded to you. Why is spooling the mail and simply *not caring about spammers rejecting their NDR returns* not an option?

Comment: When would that special case occur? If the connection drops?
The problem is that the NDR fails to deliver, and then exim freezes it, tried to notify me about it, maybe again triggering my providers’s spam filter. And I regularly have to delete frozen mails. Maybe that’s just normal.

Comment: Are you certain you *have to delete* frozen mail? There should be automatic retention limits configured for this - by default.

Comment: The case I describe happens when the sender has shorter timeouts than it should have, or when your proxy is really slow in forwarding (limited in bandwidth). The sender might then retry the same message over and over, believing it was not accepted.

Comment: I found the “delete frozen messages after x days” setting a few days ago, so less bad. But I'd still prefer for this problem to just disappear :-)